# What's the difference between foreign keys and accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

Just as the title says, I don't know what the real differences are between `foreign_key` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. I've googled around a bit and read through the API docs. But the difference is unclear.

Comment: I didn't know  there were any similarities between them.

Comment: Not necessarily saying that there are similarities..It seems like I could use a foreign_key instead of an accepts_nested_attributes_for...but I don't know why I could not.

Comment: Both are totally different.`foreign_key` used to implement the `relation` between two or more models.And `accepts_nested_attributes_for` allow you to save `attributes` on `associated records` through the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Tag accepts_nested_attributes describes a model, which has an effect on how models look. Option :foreign_key affects how tables look by creating a DBMS foreign key according to the association that uses it.

We say there is a foreign key from table T columns (c,...) referencing/to table U columns (d,...) when the values for the (c,...) subrows in T have to appear as values for the (d,...) subrows of U and each such U subrow is unique in U. This means that the corresponding models will have those fields and an object of model T with some values for fields (c,...) will have exactly one correponding object of model U with those values for fields (d,...). Telling the DBMS this allows it to check updates and optimize queries.

Models will want there to be such a constraint on the tables and/or take advantage of such a constraint. They will create foreign keys (eg in a belongs_to) or offer or not offer methods (eg one returning one value instead of a set of values) as appropriate.

Having a foreign key is relevant to accepts_nested_attributes because that allows you to use methods to update an object in another class from one that has a many-to-one relationship to it. But a foreign key could exist for other reasons. And you could have a many-to-one relationship without there being a foreign key because the target column might not be unique its table.